# Define struct inside for loop when it doesn't use the iterator

Tags: c++

First of all, don't even think about the Vulkan code, this is just an example and I just care about the struct initialization.

Imagine this as a tight render loop or something, would it be better to take that struct outside the loop since it doesn't use the `i` variable?

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < framesInFlight; ++i) {
    VkSemaphoreCreateInfo semaphoreCreateInfo = {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SEMAPHORE_CREATE_INFO,
        .pNext = nullptr,
        .flags = 0
    };

    vkCreateSemaphore(device, &semaphoreCreateInfo, nullptr, &semaphores[i]);
}
```

Or would the compiler optimize it to do so.

Comment: The answer to a lot of these type of questions is to try it and see

Comment: I would bet $100 that the compiler would optimize that away.  But if it matters that much to you, you should inspect the assembly or profile your code to be sure.

Comment: Please don't tag both c and c++, they are separate languages and have different answers to questions

Comment: Check your output with optimization turned on. If `vkCreateSemaphore` takes the struct as `const` there is a good chance the compiler is hoisting it. And just checked the api takes the struct as `const` so it's very likely that any non-horrible compiler would hoist that.

Comment: @AlanBirtles This code literally works the same way in both languages.

Comment: @Karlos I'd avoid saying that. There are significant but subtle differences that matter a lot. Not even touching on the fact you're using `nullptr` which doesn't exist in C.

Comment: @Mgetz it does take a const pointer

Comment: @Mgetz then just use NULL

Comment: This code won't work in c due to at least `nullptr`. They are separate languages and have different optimisation rules leading to different conflicting answers to your question

Comment: @AlanBirtles i guess so

Comment: `const` in C is basically just a suggestion, in C++ it's a requirement. That leads to very very different optimization results.

Comment: @Mgetz so u recomend taking a look at the assembly right?

Comment: @Karlos if you ever have a question about how something generates code, yes. It's literally the only answer. Let me introduce you to https://godbolt.org

Comment: Unless the C++ compiler can prove that the called function does not modify the object referenced by the pointer, it cannot perform this optimization. Neither can you, because this will change the code's behavior.